# Custom RNN Layer with previous input and output time steps as Inputs

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

How can I extend the SimpleRNN or create a custom layer that could use not just the previous output `y[n-1]` but also the previous output `y[n-2]` and the previous inputs `x[n-1]`, `x[n-2]`?

```
def call(self, inputs, states):
    prev_output = states[0]
    h = K.dot(inputs, self.kernel)
    output = h + K.dot(prev_output, self.recurrent_kernel)
    return output, [output]
```

My goal is to rewrite output in such a way that it fulfills this equation:
`output[n] = Wx0*input[n] + Wx1*input[n-1] + Wx2*input[n-2] Wy1*output[n-1] + Wy2*output[n-2]`